# Allow partial external access to internal website.

Tags: php, apache

We have developed a new Purchase Order application that is used to send PO's to vendors via email. The email contains a link at the bottom for the user to click to acknowledge receipt of the PO which is a link back into the system that updates the status of the PO. Doing this however exposes the login page of the application which I want to hide. Any suggest on how to hide this? We're Running an apache webserver on windows 2012 R2.

Comment: Other companies got an intranet and an extranet... looking those two keywords up, hopefully will give you some ideas. :)

Comment: set up a different authentication process for external users.  Use JWT "JSON Web Tokens" [read about it here](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519). [Here is an example of the content of a JWT](https://jwt.io/)